# Shouldn't answers today fetch more points than answers given years back?

Tags: feature-request, reputation

There are lot of SO users who have reputation running in several thousands. These are the people who have had SO accounts since a long time. I can only imagine how wonderful they would feel seeing the green pluses every time they just casually log in just to see some newbie just upvoted an answer that he gave 5 years back. There probably would have been a time when *almost* every question was a new question and thus every good answer was awell rewarded. That's why we see year old answers which keep getting several upvotes every day and thus the person who gave them still comfortably earns reputation! Fast forward 2015. SO has reached a stage when lot of questions have already been asked before and not to mention tremendous competition! On popular tags, you see 10 answers within seconds of the question being asked. A guy today has to struggle exponentially mmore than a guy,say 3 years back to earn rep.

So, I am tempted to ask this. Don't you think that new questions or answers should have a different rating system than old ones? *It's harder to fish nowadays, most of the fishes have already been caught mate* :) Would love to hear what others have to say.

Comment: If you're here just to try to "win", and not to actually help people, then I can tell you now it's not going to work out for you, especially on SO.  While SE *does* use gamification to bring game-like elements into answering questions, you have to remember that at the end of the day this is a question and answer site first, not a game.

Comment: Well we are not talking about morals. Ofcourse I fully understand the intent behind the site, but their needs to be a concept of fairness too. I guess you need to see from the POV of a newbie who wants to mix game and knowledge.

Comment: It is anyone's personal opinion how they want to benefit from the site.There are no ten commandments about it. Also, the mods know human nature(READ: of wanting to win) very well. Hence they came up with so many rules. I am just pointing to what I think is a small chink.

Comment: `but their needs to be a concept of fairness too` no, actually, there doesn't.  When I joined SO it was quite some time ago, and yet it was clear, even then that there were people ([cough] Jon Skeet [cough]) that I'd never ever reach in reputation.  That didn't stop me, or the many tens of thousands of other users, from becoming active participants.

Comment: Okay. So just imagine that in a few years,there is a stage reached when it's literally it would be like a jackpot to earn 10 points. What kind of situation would that be? What if there are 10000 Jon Skeets who answer every question as they come. Wouldn't SO have to rewrite some code then? Would you still be saying what you are saying today?

Comment: If we've literally reached the point that the entire scope of programming knowledge already existed in SO, and as a result nobody was ever capable of coming up with unique questions that hadn't already been solved with a high quality answer on the site, then *Mission ****ing Accomplished*.  (Not that that would ever happen.)   Clearly there would no longer be a need for anyone to answer questions, so there's no problem with a lack of incentive to get answerers.

Comment: If you really want to think of SO as a game (and to some extent it is), instead of trying to change the rules, how about actually trying to play it? Perhaps if you post some quality answers now, in the future they may become the next "old post that gives out rep every day". Not only does it benefit your rep, it benefits everyone else who will find your quality posts useful.

Comment: At the risk of sounding a weirdo, I have to say this. You can just assume that I am one of those guys, who hook onto the site all the time looking for some rep to feel good about himself. Who also is highly thankful to the creator of the site for it's existence because he is spending time learning stuff, even though for selfish and not philanthropic reasons. Do guys like me not deserve a little level gameplay, that rules be a little in favour if these guys who have recently learnt to be in awe of SO.

Comment: @Servy - No offence, but I must say your first comment was not very well thought off. A person here doesn't really need to be having a genuinely helpful nature to help others. Any geek XYZ who has his basics covered can just scout the entire site all day to earn rep and thus give answers and earning rep and thus in the process not give a tiny rat's a* to helping others. So you can't say that if I am not the one who likes to help others, I can't survive. As long as my answers make sense, I just might. :)

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti No because it is not the point of the site to earn reputation. It is a "goodie" to allow experienced users to have more weight in decisions and more available tools and privileges. Last thing we want is a high rep user with a lot of privileges that does not care bout the community or the main goals of the site. So no we do not want to encourage one of these guys.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti I simply said that if your goal is to "win" and be one of the people at the top of the leaderboards then it's functionally impossible.  The rep cap makes it more or less impossible for you to catch up to everyone else.  The existence of a bunch of old questions still getting rep has far less to do with it.

Comment: Related: [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202652)

Comment: Nope. You got me wrong. I am not nieve enough to even think of playing catch up with the pros. I just am of opinion that the code is flawed.

Comment: @Servy: I'm catching up just fine.. Took me a few years but I was late to the game all the same.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Jon Skeet has earned more rep in the time since you joined the site than you have.  You're much further (in absolute amount of rep) from being the top rep user now than you were 5 years ago.

Comment: @Martjin - yes life isn't :( (atleast on SO :D)

Comment: @Servy: You can see from my [network-wide reputation graph](http://stackexchange.com/users/35417/martijn-pieters?tab=reputation) I wasn't really active before summer 2012. I was [#1 overall in 2013](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2013-01-01), [#2 in 2014](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2014-01-01). But realistically I can *never* catch up to Jon. If he stopped posting now and deleted all his answers it'd take 3-4 years to catch up to him. If he coursed on his current answers and never added new, it'd take about 8 years. But that was never a goal.

Answer (score 8):

Are old answers any less helpful than new answers?

Votes are a measure of reach and helpfulness. An old answer that attracts hundreds of votes has those votes because it reached - and helped - thousands of people.

It's true that a good answer can acquire upvotes for weeks, months, and years to come - but good advice lasts decades. A great answer should be rewarded as such.

---

Also, we're here to help people as a whole. While it's true that most of the low-hanging fruit is picked within (most sites') first couple years of existence, that doesn't mean we can't help people. You absolutely still can.

Comment: I disagree. It is not only answers we are rewarding, but the person who gave that answer. Why isn't a system implemented so that answers after certain time stop earning points to the poster. Of course the answer would still be valid. If rep was money, rich are getting exponentially richer than poors. This would create what we refer as Economic disparity.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti You're thinking about rep in terms of comparison between users. In reality, your reputation isn't worth less because someone else has more. Reputation isn't used to buy goods and services, so it isn't subject to inflation or economic disparity.

Comment: @Emrakul Well, technically rep *does* inflate and there *is* a large (and increasing) disparity.  It's just that we don't *care*; it doesn't actually cause real problems.

Comment: @Servy ...that's fair. It really depends on what you mean by "inflation," though - in classical economics, the value of money inflates when the consumer price index for goods goes up - but I do see what you mean. (Though this is a hilariously pedantic side-topic.)

Comment: @Emrakul Ah, I see what you mean now.  The buying power of one Imaginary Internet Point isn't decreasing; it's staying constant at 0.  I was thinking of equating inflation to being proportional to the amount of the currency in circulation, but that's only a valid transformation when the value is non-zero.

Comment: So if rep, isn't worth jack s***, then why exactly, people have rep? What purpose does it solve? Also, would you be shocked if tomorrow you wake and find your rep reset to 100 :P

Comment: @Servy Yeah, pretty much. I do see what you mean, though.  If we think about it in terms of "how much people care that I have X reputation," using [how much] as a quantity to compare against, you may have a point... hm.

Comment: @Sourav Reputation is an acknowledgement that what you did helped people, and that others found it useful. I'd be irked if my reputation were reset, because it would mean that (excluding a code error) my content was no longer considered helpful. It's also representative of how much the site trusts me, so it would be, in essence, saying that "we no longer trust you."

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti Rep has value to the degree that it affects site permissions.  If I lost all my rep I'd care that I'd be seeing more ads, couldn't edit posts without review, couldn't vote to close/delete crap content, etc.  How much rep anyone else has earned has no real bearing on any of those though; to that extent the value of rep remains constant.

Comment: So, in your own words, rep is something which is accumulated. That's exactly what is wrong with it. It should be an indicator of how much effort a person puts in today(a fiercely competitive world) than years back(a relatively calm world). This is my personal opinion. In any sport the most reputed player is determined more by his/her current form, not so much the form 10 years back.

Comment: "Reputation isn't used to buy goods and services" hey, wut? And bounties? :D

Answer (score 4):

> It's harder to fish nowadays, most of the fishes have already been caught mate

What is *fishing* in this situation? Acquiring reputation points? Because that's not the point of stack exchange. The whole point is not to stack reputation and see who can gather the most. It is to ask and answer relevant questions in order to help people get the information they need. Reputation is just a scale of the overall experience you gathered in the site.

Back to your analogy. It is not harder to fish nowadays because it is not harder than before to ask or answer questions. Yes a lot of topics have been covered but considering the number of question we get every single day, we are far from a point where you can't ask good questions anymore.

Unfortunately, your post suggest that you care a bit too much about what reputation is worth around here.

Comment: I am really amused as to why you guys are looking down upon me as if caring about earning rep is a really bad thing. Now, back to my analogy, fishing **is** harder not because number of fishes have come down but because number of fishermen have come up. And there are fishermen who still get royalty if once catching a big fish. Get my analogy now?

Comment: I got it the first time, the thing is I don't think it is appropriate since getting reputation points is not the goal of this site. About that royalty thing of course they are still given points since their questions help users and then users upvote them so they should get as much points as you would get from helping someone with one of your newest posts.

Comment: Back to square one. I am not saying that they don't deserve the score. I am just saying that everybody in the site should have the opportunity to grow at the same pacE, which is far from being so. And don't get me wrong man. This is my first question here and I'm already have it rough :) So maybe I am coming out a bit defensive. I don't mean to demean anyone here.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti The rep cap means that everyone essentially *does* grow at the same pace when they're quite active regardless of how long they've been active and regardless of how many old questions they have.  If you're an active user you're getting ~200 rep a day, the same as most of the people with 200k+ rep.

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti Servy beat me to it. We do grow at the exact same pace. It is only possible for a user to make 200 reputation per day and it is possible for all users to make that 200 reputation per day.

Comment: True, but for ppl who have been here long, rep comes faster and easier

Comment: I've been here for about 3 years and I don't feel as if I'm getting fast and easy reputation.

Comment: I meant relatively.