# Do simpler questions seem to attract more upvotes?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, up-votes, question-difficulty

I have been noticing over the last month (on Stack Overflow), that simpler (perhaps somewhat duplicate) questions seem to get a lot of attention, as compared to the more challenging long-ish questions.

As a result, the answers tend to receive a greater number of upvotes (simply due to greater views) even though the answer might be a copy of an already existing Q/A. Moderators do take care to mark most of these questions as [duplicate], but many slip through. What could be a possible solution to this?

Comment: Most users are not moderators, if users with enough reputation to flag questions are not flagging questions as duplicate, you should start flagging those possible duplicates as duplicates.  What exactly is your question though?

Comment: Related: [The bikeshed problem and Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31253/21960)

Comment: What is the problem with this as you see it? Some questions attract more upvotes than others? Is that a problem?

Comment: My effort is generally not proportional to the points I receive. I get maximum points for answering *fast* on really simple questions and I never receive more than 25 points on harder questions where I had to actually sit down and code

Comment: Well if you're only answering questions for points then carry on answering easy questions :)

Comment: This is certainly true for the easiest of questions. And most of us started that way. But after a while it gets boring and stupid as you are realizing now. So some of us prefer to play the "bigger game" which is much more interesting and self-fulfilling. Recent example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat

Comment: Yep, this is a thing.  Of course, asking simple questions on some tags (e.g., javascript, php, c++) are about as likely to get you killed as upvoted.  Now look at my hat.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265165/rewarding-overzealous-users-for-answering-duplicate-questions-is-undermining-the http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297853/are-we-too-preoccupied-with-easy-questions http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334149/how-can-i-get-my-non-trivial-questions-better-received

Comment: or http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31253/193412 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem?rq=1

Comment: [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202652/165773)

Answer (score 2):

Because people don't bother searching for duplicates.

Because people like helping others and would rather spit out an answer than try to be part of community moderation.

Because the system is setup to reward answering those questions and not hard questions.

Because you can vote to close and still answer.

Because answering first is often the best for reputation.

Lots of reasons.