# Is asking general questions a good way to get reputation?

Tags: discussion, questions

It seems people get more reputation for questions that aren't specific or questions that aren't to solve their problem. Is it a good way to get reputation to ask general questions rather than specific questions that you have about a topic?

Example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259278/context-manager-for-pdfpages) gets little rep but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) gets millions of views and tons of rep.

Comment: [The Trouble With Popularity...](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/)

Comment: The first example is probably a real problem but the second one is really vague and there is probably no specific problem.

Comment: Also, the first one you linked - it's an hour old right now compared to a question from yeeaarrss ago. You can't reasonably compare the two at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Life isn't fair](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202652/life-isnt-fair)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My understanding is that Stack Exchange sites are designed for focussed Q&A.

Even though you may find highly upvoted general questions, they will often be old and, if asked today, might be quickly closed as too broad.

To deliberately ask general questions nowadays will, I think, be a risky strategy for someone seeking to build reputation because along with close votes they may also attract downvotes, if they are seen to be lacking research effort or otherwise not useful.

Answer (score 7):

You're comparing an eight-year-old question to one asked today. Those are two different environments, two different SO's.

SO back then was this new medium you could ask questions on and get a good response. **It was new**, so the questions were naturally general. Imagine, as a physics fan, being given an opportunity to pay a visit to a well-known physicist; naturally, you wouldn't ask them about the trivial details of [the M theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory), but really general aspects of their career, like how they came up with their most famous theory.

The SQL injection question is the general question, and those have been asked already. SO is now like the experience of being with that physicist for eight years, and all those "how did you come up with your greatest invention?" or "How did you deal with this big problem in your research?" have been asked, albeit not by you.

So if you go today and ask the same questions from the physicist again, you're going to be directed at all the documented answers at best.

If I were to offer a piece of advice, I would advise not to ask unless you really need to. Don't try to come up with questions, and don't throw anything you think resembles a question into a post and move on. Make sure there are no answers out there for your problem, which is easy, thanks to SO. You just need to look for answers in a few places.

Also, most of the problems solve themselves when you specify what you've got, what you haven't, and what the problem really is, methodologically.

Answer (score 4):

You are not the first to report that sometimes vague, general, and popular questions appear to get more rewards than crisp, focused, and perhaps difficult questions. You see a handful of examples of undeserving "Winners". But what you don't see is all the deleted (or just downvoted so much they don't appear on the front page) examples. Getting through the "SO hates new users" gauntlet to enjoy all those undeserved upvotes is pretty rare. More importantly, such questions almost never get good answers, which is really the point.

To answer your literal question, no, it's not a good strategy because your question will likely be closed and deleted before it can earn you rep. To answer your implied "isn't it unfair that some people get what they don't deserve?" question, perhaps it is. The system minimizes this effect, but doesn't take it to zero. Be glad it is minimized though. Some day you will have enough rep to see deleted questions, and then you'll see what you were spared seeing today.

Comment: Someday..... :)